# C# SqlParameter properties throw null reference immediately after construction

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlparameter

Consider the following program

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SqlParameter parambe = new SqlParameter("@myParam", "myValue");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

and observe the result, properties are throwing `NullReferenceException`s!

[image: properties of SqlParameter throwing NullRefs on construction]

**Why is this?**

These properties do not appear to be on [the documentation of the `SqlParameter` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx) (it is also not on any object in the inheritance chain).

- How can I learn more about these properties functions?

  - Where do these properties come from?
  - Is there a good reason they throw exceptions?

Edit: To clarify some things from the comments,

- I understand this is ***not*** my application throwing an exception, rather its the debugger throwing an exception attempting to access the properties.
- I have linked the MSDN documentation above, but *the properties are not documented*.
- Here is [the referencesource of SqlParameter](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlParameter.cs,d54848d811d7dfe0) (thank you for this suggestion), but I can't make heads or tails of it. The suspicious section to me

---

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
internal void AssertCachedPropertiesAreValid()
{
    AssertPropertiesAreValid(_coercedValue, _coercedValueIsSqlType, _coercedValueIsDataFeed, IsNull);
}

[Conditional("DEBUG")]
internal void AssertPropertiesAreValid(object value, bool? isSqlType = null, bool? isDataFeed = null, bool? isNull = null)
{
    Debug.Assert(!isSqlType.HasValue || (isSqlType.Value == (value is INullable)), "isSqlType is incorrect");
    Debug.Assert(!isDataFeed.HasValue || (isDataFeed.Value == (value is DataFeed)), "isDataFeed is incorrect");
    Debug.Assert(!isNull.HasValue || (isNull.Value == ADP.IsNull(value)), "isNull is incorrect");
}
```

However, this doesn't really help me understand *why* it's occurring (it's not like I've done anything to put this object into a bad state), so maybe there is a good reason - or is this just an oversight in a system library?

Comment: The debugger trying to access them gets a NullReferenceException. That doesn't mean your code has actually thrown a NullReferenceException.

Comment: That is just the debugger trying to evaluate everything it can, it is not a runtime error. You will see this behavior often on all types of things.

Comment: `How can I learn more...` MSDN?

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/

Comment: These properties are not public so there is no need to care or learn about them - they are not part of public interface of SqlParameter.

Comment: You should specify a datatype for your parameter.

Comment: @SeanLange 99% of the time you don't have to do it. unless its a varchar column

Comment: @Steve I would argue that you should always specify the datatype. Otherwise you are counting on the system to guess correctly which it doesn't always do. If you are creating a sql parameter then surely the developer knows the datatype.

Comment: @SeanLange the system is pretty good at determining the type most of the time. The only type I have ran into problem is string which it will be set to nvarchar instead of varchar if you don't specify it

Comment: And dates or decimals to name a couple others. There are several more datatypes it sometimes gets wrong when it guesses.Why risk the chance, just be explicit and avoid all confusion.